# How do I add an Fcurve Noise modifier with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, fcurves

I am looking to add a Noise Modifier to a Node in the Compositor. I have added a keyframe to the Node but when I try and add the Noise Modifier, it's obviously not correct. I guess it's space_type sensitive. It will only work when the Panel is in the Graph Editor.

Here is the failure I have so far:

```py
import bpy

class TestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_idname = "TEST_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Test'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('node.mod_operator') 

class NODE_OT_TEST(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Gamma Noise"
    bl_idname = 'node.mod_operator'

    def execute(self, context):

        sc = bpy.context.scene
        tree = sc.node_tree

        gamma_node = tree.nodes.new(type= 'CompositorNodeGamma')
        gamma_node.inputs[1].default_value = 2
        gamma_node.inputs[1].keyframe_insert("default_value", frame= 30)
        gamma_node.select = True

        #this will only work when the Panel is in the Graph Editor. 
        noise_mod = bpy.ops.graph.fmodifier_add(type= 'NOISE')

        return {'FINISHED'}       

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TestPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(NODE_OT_TEST)




def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TestPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NODE_OT_TEST)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I'm sure there is another way to do it but I can not figure it out.. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Using API methods takes away the need for context***

Inserting a keyframe on a node, adds an fcurve to the scene nodetree action.

From the datapath, find the fcurve and add a new modifier of type 'NOISE' and set the appropriate settings.

For example

```
def execute(self, context):
    sc = context.scene
    tree = sc.node_tree

    gamma_node = tree.nodes.new(type="CompositorNodeGamma")
    gamma_node.inputs[1].default_value = 2
    gamma_node.inputs[1].keyframe_insert("default_value", frame= 30)
    gamma_node.select = True
    # datapath of newly added node
    data_path = f'nodes["{gamma_node.name}"].inputs[1].default_value'
    fcurves = tree.animation_data.action.fcurves
    # find the fcurve (should be there)
    fc = fcurves.find(data_path)
    if fc:
        # add the modifier and set props
        nm = fc.modifiers.new('NOISE')
        nm.strength = 2
        nm.depth = 1

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Code assumes using python >= 3.6 with fstrings, else use older string formatting eg

```
data_path = 'nodes["%s"].inputs[1].default_value' % gamma_node.name
```

> For future reference, how would I find the Data path?

Two useful methods for this, firstly `path_from_id(property)`  See how it is similar to keyframe insert.  Some python console test code.  Autocomplete on the opening brace gives a run down

```
>>> C.scene.node_tree.nodes['Gamma'].inputs[1].path_from_id(
path_from_id(property="")
.. method:: path_from_id(property="")
Returns the data path from the ID to this object (string).
:arg property: Optional property name which can be used if the path is
   to a property of this object.
:type property: string
:return: The path from :class:`bpy.types.bpy_struct.id_data`
   to this struct and property (when given).
:rtype: str
```

The result

```
>>> C.scene.node_tree.nodes['Gamma'].inputs[1].path_from_id("default_value")
'nodes["Gamma"].inputs[1].default_value'
```

The id object the path is referenced from

```
>>> C.scene.node_tree.nodes['Gamma'].inputs[1].id_data
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree

>>>
```

Hence the action is on the node tree, and adding the datapath gives us the property keyframed or driven.

Comment: Ah man, Thanks for your help @batFINGER I am clearly new to python and this is the first time I have used a data_path. For future reference, how would I find the Data path?

Comment: Happy to help.  Question is clear, shows an effort has been made,  has minimal working code. (_ie_ can copy paste into text editor and run)  Tossed up whether to explain datapath better.  Edited.